# Typescript error - 'value' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)

Tags: typescript

New to Typescript. I am getting an error on the setting of x. I understand the error, and I have read a few articles on similar errors, but can't seem to find a way around it. Any pointers?

```
class Point {
    constructor(private _x?: number, private _y?: number) {}

    get x() {
        return this._x;
    }

    set x(value) {
        if (value < 0) throw new Error("Invalid"); // Getting 'value' is possibly 'undefined'.ts(18048)

        this._x = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add a type annotation `set x(value: number)`

Comment: @CoryKramer Thanks. Interestingly this then causes a different issue with the getter returning the value, on the return line - Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.ts(2322)

Comment: _x is optional so it could be undefined.

Comment: why do you have the question marks in your constructor ? Is there a scenario in which it makes sense to create a Point with only one or zero coordinates ? If you want to have default values, you should probably do this instead : ```constructor(private _x: number = 0, private _y: number = 0) ```

Comment: Got it - thanks. I was following a tutorial, but presumably on an older version of TS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends a bit, at what stage you want to allow that `_x` is undefined. You could annotate it like this

```
class Point {
    // allow _x to be undefined after construct (by marking it with '?')
    constructor(private _x?: number, private _y?: number) {}

    // getter returns x, which can be a number or undefined (if it hasn't been set yet)
    get x(): number | undefined {
        return this._x;
    }

    // setter only accepts a number. This also makes sure, the comparison 'value < 0' is safe
    set x(value: number) {
        if (value < 0) throw new Error("Invalid"); 
        this._x = value;
    }
}
```

See this [ts-playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAEAKD2BLAdgF2gbwLAChr%20mHmQlQCcBXYVeMgCgAczEA3MVAU2gH0APAfgBc0ZBQC2AIw5kANNCat2XbgE8hI8VLIBKTAF9cuAtADmHdLzrbhoydOgAfaBWQATDgDMUHV5iPGCMnMKMmRoVAALRAgAOj4Abn98Axwk6AhzaEs2EAoOG01pXWw8APxED2g6HLzoAB5oAAZdSLJ4AHcRDk6AUTI2%20gAiAElkHMRXQe146AB6WegAcXNUFBNoAHIajg3oaPl4KEQJEBVNl3cvZB8NmNQIOgBGAA5GgBZn7UNSssjouN40AAvNBtokftAUnogA). If you want to model the class in a way that `_x` is always a number and therefore also needs to be provided on constructor, this would be enough:

```
class Point {
    constructor(private _x: number, private _y: number) {}

    get x() {
        return this._x;
    }

    set x(value) {
        if (value < 0) throw new Error("Invalid"); 
        this._x = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: A clear answer - thanks. Makes sense now.